# Writing a comment at the top of an .xml file?

Tags: java, xml, database

I'm currently writing a program that writes a .xml file. I want to place a comment at the top of the file (first line) that says something about how altering the code will mess it up. Is this possible using an XMLEncoder?

Here is my code:

```
private static void serializeToXML(ArrayList<Item> list)
    { 
        try
        {
            XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(getSaveLocation())));
            encoder.writeObject(list);
            encoder.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Error writing list to XML File.");
        } 
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot have *anything* before the `<?xml ... ?>` prolog in an XML document. So, no, it is not possible at all, regardless of which API you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You cannot have anything **before** the `<?xml ... ?>`.

I suppose the following xml should be what you may want:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!--Some insightful commentary here-->
<SomePojo>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>pojo1</name>
</SomePojo>
```

You can try jackson-dataformat-xml.

Test Code

```
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class XMLWriteCommentTest {

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    // First create Stax components we need
    XMLInputFactory  xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    XMLOutputFactory xmlOutputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
    XMLStreamWriter sw = xmlOutputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(out);

    // then Jackson components
    XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper(xmlInputFactory);

    sw.writeStartDocument();
    // comment
    sw.writeComment("Some insightful commentary here");
    // Write whatever content POJOs...
    mapper.writeValue(sw, new SomePojo("1", "pojo1"));

    sw.writeEndDocument();
    // getResult
    String xml = out.toString();
    System.out.println(xml);
    }
}    
class SomePojo {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public SomePojo(String id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
<version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: An XML file doesn't *have* to have an XML declaration. So if the question is whether you can have an XML comment as the first thing of an XML file, the answer is 1. generally yes, and 2. with XMLEncoder (or any other API): only if you can make it omit the XML declaration. But I guess your post is answering what OP actually wanted to know - whether and how you can insert an XML comment before the first element.